# Changing GKE cluster subnet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to change the IP range of the subnet used for a GKE cluster. Ideally, I would like to just change the subnet and have the everything just work, but that obviously does not work, as my new ranges are not a superset of the existing range.

Short of deleting the whole thing and recreating it, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is immutable to change the IP range of the subnet used for a GKE cluster with a newly different range. You can only modify your current IP range with the superset of the existing range.

I would also like to point out that you can't change your subnet for any GCE instance once it is [created](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#limitations).